# ninject Inheritance security rules violatedby type: 'Ninject.Web.NinjectHttpModule' in mvc4

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject.web.mvc

I have a mvc4 web application. I decided to use ninject.mvc3. so I installed it from nuget.
But it is throwing this exception:

```
Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'Ninject.Web.NinjectHttpModule'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

  private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel(); //Throws exception this line
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
            return kernel;
        }
```

I tried to add  `'<trust level="Full"/>'` in web.config. Also I tried to add

`'[assembly: System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]'`
 in NinjectWebComman.cs. But again it didn't run.

What should I do?.
Thanks.